# Can I hide jquery version used in website?

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to hide `Jquery` version in a Web Application?

My client needs this requirement.

Comment: The only way is to drop the jQuery. What ever you load to a public web page is ... well ... public, you can't hide anything.

Comment: Why does the client want this? The underlying goal could potentially be achieved in other ways.

Comment: Client needs this for security purpose just to hide jquery version so that libraries which are compatible with current jquery version.

Answer (score 2):

Not in any practical way.

---

The URL usually reveals it, although that is the easiest thing to change.

`$().jquery` reveals the version number. It would take some hacking to conceal that. (Some libraries depend on it to make sure they are compatible with the loaded version of jQuery so doing that could break other things).

And it is pretty trivial to diff the downloaded source file against a set of known versions of jQuery if someone really wanted to find out.

---

It *shouldn't* matter anyway. If you are using an ancient version of jQuery with known security problems then, rather than resorting to security through obscurity, upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.